# How to send to control C# one object some strings using Jquery $ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

```
// mycontroller
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Obj1> Post([FromBody]Obj2 val, string str1, string str2)
{
Model1 = new function1();
Obj1[] res;

res= client.function1(val, str1, str2);
return res;
}

//myscript
send1.click(function (e) {
$.ajax({
url: action,
datetype: "JSON",
data: {
  'val': JSON.stringify($(this).serialize()),
},
cache: false,
type: "POST",
beforeSend: function (data) {}
)
.done()
.fail()
.always()
})
```

I dont see the object in controller side, maybe some error in js send1  somebody can a help me? The return res is a empty object, this is ok but the object and strings post from ajax not received in controller.

Answer (score 0):

For `Obj2 val` to be parsed into an object, your MVC project needs to have an `ModelBinder` which understands `Obj2`. It can't magically interpret JSON strings into any kind of Class.

You can test this by replacing Obj2

```
Post([FromBody]Obj2 val, string str1, string str2)
```

with

```
Post([FromBody]string val, string str1, string str2)
```

and see if you get the JSON string? If that works your next step is to convert the string into an instance of `Obj2`. You have to write the code for this; it can't happen magically.

The standard place to put that code is in a `ModelBinder` and wire it up in your `Glolbal.asax.cs` `ApplicationStart`